# Pass component method as a parameter to a class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component `First` that creates a new instance of a `Worker` class

On class creation I want to pass the `Read` method  as a callback method to this class. This class will do some work and when done will invoke it.

I know it's possible in plain JS, can I do it in Angular 6?

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-campaign-settings',
   templateUrl: './campaign-settings.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./campaign-settings.component.css']
})
export class First implements OnInit {

worker:Worker=null;

  Work() {

    worker=new Worker(this.Read);
    worker.Run();
  }
  Read() {
    //do stuff

  }
}

  export class Worker implements OnInit {

  callback:any;

   constructor(i_callback:any) {

  }

  Run()
  {
    callback();
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Angular is built on TypeScript, which is just a typed superset of JS, so anything you can do in JS syntax will pretty much work in Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Angular strongly discourages to pass around callbacks or references to other classes.

Instead, a parent can listen to events that a child emits, and then execute the code that you are trying to put in a callback.

This way, the child does not even need to know that the parent exists or what methods the parent has.

[You can find an example of an Event Emitter and Subscriber here](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).